# Data Portability in GDPR

Tags: gdpr

I've reading:

https://gdpr-info.eu/art-20-gdpr/

It says:

> The data subject shall have the right to receive the personal data concerning him or her, which he or she has provided to a controller, in a structured, commonly used and machine-readable format and have the right to transmit those data to another controller without hindrance from the controller to which the personal data have been provided..

I don't understand this. It talks about "personal data concerning him". What does that mean, not all data?

I'm looking for a directive that says we must be able to get ALL data in a portable form so that we can transfer it.

Comment: the law mainly refers to personal data. this article solely allows you to request all data that relates to the person requesting it (if data relates to that person, it's  "personal data"). there is no article which would require all data to be provided...(that would also be very odd).

Comment: Isn't it personal data if I created all the data? This particular system is a cloud accounting system, so all data I've put in there is like "personal"?

Comment: no, the data would need to contain personal data (i.e. like names, social security numbers, etc), and subsequently data linked to that data...

Comment: @JasonHunter belongs the data in the accounting system to your personal expenses, bank account, etc? Or is it from a legal person instead of a natural person?

Answer (score 1):

> '[Personal Data](https://www.itgovernance.eu/blog/en/the-gdpr-what-exactly-is-personal-data)' means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person (‘data subject’).

For example, my handle on this website is 'personal data': this answer isn't if my user name is removed from it.